# Pip is not caching all installed packages

Tags: python, pip

I recently noticed that pip does not cache all the packages installed which is quite annoying as when I create a new virtual environment, it will re-download the package.
I tested it with django for example. I `pip install django`.
It installs the following packages `sqlparse, pytz, asgiref, django`.
But when I do `pip cache list 'django*'`, django is not listed in the cache.

Then I start a new virtual environment with virtualenvwrapper and `pip install django`, it downloads the package.

I am on Macos. We use a corporate Nexus as a pypi proxy.
What I am missing here?

EDIT: Other environment information: macOS 10.15.6 and Python 3.6.8.

Comment: I just tried (macOS 10.14.6, with Python 3.8.1): I'm not seeing this behaviour: the second time (in a virtualenv created within one minute of the first), Django is installed from the cache (Django-3.1.1-py3-none-any.whl).

Comment: Did you run pip the first time outside a virtualenv?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use Python 3.6.8 (because we cannot yet use a more recent version on my project) and macOS 10.15.6, I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: The first pip was run outside the virtual environment. But both (virtual env and the main installation) report the same cache location.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I did wonder if `pip` outside the virtualenv did not correspond to `python` used for the virtualenv (and thus Django was installed for two different Python versions), but if both times the same location is used, that seems unlikely.